# Retrieving and displaying an image from folder outside Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I display the image with path that has backward slashes? I can do it from within Visual Studio files using forward slashes, but not outside Visual Studio.

```
@"C:\Users\sam\Downloads\nanas.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can potentially do:

```
file:///C|/Users/sam/Downloads/nanas.png
```

However, I say potentially, because this depends a lot on permissions. Additionally, it will only work if the file exists at that exact location on the *client's* machine. If you were to deploy this live, anyone who didn't have a "sam" user with a file named "nanas.png" in their Downloads folder would get a broken image.